# Finding actual memory space used by NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, memory

How can I get the size in memory of an `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` in a particular application?

Comment: With size, do you mean the number of elements or the number of bytes in memory?

Comment: Please rephrase your question's title.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Use `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary`'s `count` method to get the number of item in an `NSMutableArray`

```
    int numberOfItemInAnArray = [myArray count];
    int numberOfItemInAnDict =  [myDirectionary count];
```

Answer (score 13):

Your may get size with this code, but this don't beauty)

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_yourDictionary];    
long size = [data length];
```

All objects in Array / Dictionary must satisfy NSCoding protocol (if they aren't standart classes like as NSString, NSInteger, etc)

Comment: Actually, you can't insert an NSInteger in an Array. You would have to encapsulate it in a NSNumber or NSValue;

Answer (score 1):

With `[myDictionary count]` and `[myArray count]`.